# Design query for job site using subdomains

Tags: 7, subsites

I'm designing a job site in D7. Ideally for better SEO each state or city should be in separate subdomain(this what I've learnt).

For city Paris it'd look like: paris.myjobsite.com

I'd post jobs using taxonomy categorization e.g. city,state, zip code, field, salary, qualifications.

Now I can host a new Drupal site on each sub domain so for 100 city/states it'd have 100 separate Drupal databases using multi site setup.

The other solution is to have a rewrite rule translating subdomain to site's internal url.

I'm unable to think beyond this.

I'd appreciate help as to how this design issue can be met in Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module was meant for: multiple sites with their own URL, running out of the same database, sharing some but not all content.

In your case, each city would be an "affiliate" site.  Each subsite could have it's own theme, but they could same theme, too.

The end result is all of your subsites run out of the same Drupal installation and share the same admin.

I have only used the Drupal 6 version, but it works fairly well and integrates nicely with other modules, especially ctools, Views, and Panels.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Purl](http://drupal.org/project/purl), and would perhaps also benefit from using [Spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces).